# Why does std::istreambuf_iterator fail boost's SinglePassIterator concept check?

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, range, concept

The following program:

```
#include <boost/range/concepts.hpp>
#include <iterator>
#include <istream>

using boost::range_detail::SinglePassIteratorConcept;


int main()
{
    BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT(( SinglePassIteratorConcept<std::istreambuf_iterator<char>> ));
}
```

Fails to compile with both MSVC and gcc. The MSVC error is as follows:

```
D:\libraries\boost\boost/range/concepts.hpp(157) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'char' to 'char &'
        D:\libraries\boost\boost/range/concepts.hpp(147) : while compiling class template member function 'boost::range_detail::SinglePassIteratorConcept<Iterator>::~SinglePassIteratorConcept(void)'
        with
        [
            Iterator=std::istreambuf_iterator<char,std::char_traits<char>>
        ]
        D:\libraries\boost\boost/concept/detail/has_constraints.hpp(42) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::range_detail::SinglePassIteratorConcept<Iterator>' being compiled
        with
        [
            Iterator=std::istreambuf_iterator<char,std::char_traits<char>>
        ]
        D:\libraries\boost\boost/concept/detail/msvc.hpp(58) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::concepts::not_satisfied<Model>' being compiled
        with
        [
            Model=boost::range_detail::SinglePassIteratorConcept<std::istreambuf_iterator<char,std::char_traits<char>>>
        ]
        test.cpp(10) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::concepts::require<Model>' being compiled
        with
        [
            Model=boost::range_detail::SinglePassIteratorConcept<std::istreambuf_iterator<char,std::char_traits<char>>>
        ]
D:\libraries\boost\boost/range/concepts.hpp(160) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'char' to 'char &'
```

As a result, Boost.Range algorithms like `boost::copy` do not work with `istreambuf_iterator`.

What is going on here? What can I do to fix it or work around it?

**EDIT**: The proximate cause of the error seems to be that `istreambuf_iterator`'s `reference_type` is `char&`, but it's `operator*` returns `char`. For a well-formed iterator, shouldn't `operator*` always return `reference_type`?

Comment: idk, but it seems to be a good catch! :-) perhaps ask it on boost mailing list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only requirement of the type of `operator*` of an `InputIterator` is that it be convertible to `value_type` (§24.1.1/2). Since it's meaningless to assign a value to the result of `operator*` for an `istreambuf_iterator`, it would be incorrect for it to return a reference or any kind of lvalue. Boost is in error to check for that property.